# ASP.NET web forms Server Side Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am looking for the best practice for validating a form.

I have worked with the asp.net validation controls in the past, but I cant say I'm too fond of them. I personally feel they complicate the aspx page itself and are not that flexible in terms of coloring or displaying certain notifications for the user. I like full control in case changes need to be made in the future.

I have worked with custom validation in the past. Wrote my own methods and returned the page with the appropriate error message/coloring if needed. But I'm not sure it was the best design. Should I write my methods in the page code file itself and acces the controls and the page directly, should I make a business object and give the values as parameters to a function and return errormessages?

I cant seem to find a good design for my validation.

What do you use? The asp.net controls? A custom way of validation? And if custom how do you implement it?

Thanks

Comment: I use asp.net validation controls, in my opinion they're the best. Although occasionally I will use javascript bubbles but they will simply be for user interface, they will never replace my asp.net validators.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really looking for flexibility then obviously MVC is the answer.

However, your question is about Web Forms and I have no problem with the validation controls.

Using the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) is a good way of making the controls more flexible.

I would certainly put the actual validation logic in your domain models.

You can change the colours of the error text using CSS, which is the right place for such styling.